# extract paths from output of fs_usage

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I am a bit rusty on RegExp and sed (also Mac's version vs GNU's differences didn't help on my attempts) and after quite some tries [a couple of hours], I haven't managed yet to accomplish to parse an input like this:

```
16:32:07.961689  stat64                                 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/CoreBluetooth                                                                                           0.000007   JavaApplicationS.65394
16:32:07.961742  stat64                                 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DebugSymbols.framework/Versions/A/DebugSymbols                                                                                      0.000006   JavaApplicationS.65394
16:32:07.961764  stat64                                 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication                                                                            0.000007   JavaApplicationS.65394
16:32:07.961785  stat64                                 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Versions/A/Symbolication                                                                                    0.000007   JavaApplicationS.65394
16:32:07.961830  stat64                                 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeechRecognitionCore.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognitionCore                                                                    0.000008   JavaApplicationS.65394
16:32:07.962321  open              F=3        (RW____)  /dev/dtracehelper                                                                                                                                                     0.000061   JavaApplicationS.65394
16:32:07.968239  stat64                 [  2]           /AppleInternal>>>>>>>>>>
```

And extract only the paths. Note that the number of column varies, I guess that what I want is anything that is attached to / character, that is surrounded by spaces. Also, sometimes several paths appear on the same line e.g.

```
16:32:06.706726    WrData[A]       D=0x13589148  B=0x100000 /dev/disk0s2  /private/var/folders/92/663yx9fn2036kz6pb3kr8z0r0000gp/0/com.apple.LaunchServices-107502.csstore~
```

In these cases it would be awesome to either: output both /dev/disk0s2 and /private.. or **just** /private.. would also be fine.

So, basically all of the files written or read, as reported by Mac OS X fs_usage tool. The solution doesn't have to be sed based, and I could also write some code for this, but before I do that I just wanna know if there is an 'easier' way.

Thanks!

Comment: erm, sorry if this should be on superuser instead, I did find similar posts here on stackoverflow, and I could not find any info on what is appropriate on which website

Comment: Something like `grep -o '/[^ ]*'` might work for you.

Comment: Maybe this could help `sudo fs_usage | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3`

Comment: @microspino: NOze, because the number of columns varies, i.e. some columns, sometimes have no value, this mean that I would print something other than what I was expecting. Which could then perhaps use the output from that to allow to further process the file... but still not the solution, tks for the contribution though

Comment: @EtanReisner: thanks mate, I didn't know grep could do that. It works, only for the detail that some of the files had the > char, so I'L'I's solution is more complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `egrep`, which can handle regular expressions:

```
egrep -o '/[^ >]*' file
```

**Result:**

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/
...
```

Comment: perfect, had no idea that grep could do that, i.e. filter within a line. For those of you then wanting to, like me, make sure that there are no repeated entries, do something like `egrep -o '/[^ >]*' file | sort | uniq > pathsFiltered`

Answer (score 1):

A word of caution: `fs_usage` truncates long paths (from the beginning, not at the end) even if run with `-w`, so they won't all start with `/`.
I found this thread having the same problem to solve, and I elaborate on the egrep solution:
`cut -c 57-222 file.txt | egrep -o '[^ ].*/[^>]+[^ ]'`
which seems to work with the truncated ones too (but do not take my word for it).

Explanation: `cut` extracts the columns where paths actually are, then `egrep` crudely extracts strings with at least one `/` in them (also allowing spaces in the pathnames).

TBH I'm not sure my solution is 100% correct (probably not).

By the way, besides the truncated ones, tracing applications I also get paths not starting with `/` which turn out to be relative to somewhere inside the app package.
Example (using Xcode 7.3.1 as test subject):
`A/Resources/XCWelcome-NewCheckoutTemplate.pdf` is actually `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XCWelcome-NewCheckoutTemplate.pdf`
Example of truncated path: `ations/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform/Developer/Library/GPUTools/PlugIns/GLToolsMobileAnalysis.gtplugin/Contents/Resources/PlugIn.plist`

NOTE: [fs_usage sources](https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-880.60.2/fs_usage.tproj/) confirm the truncation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PCRE/Perl, you will be able to extract data from this type of log with a long regex with optional groups.

Here is one I came up with:

```
(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(?:(F=\d+)\s+)?(?:(\[[^]]*\])\s+)?(?:(\S+)\s+)?((?:\/[^\/\n]*)*\/\S+)(?:\s+(\d\.\d+))?\s*(.*)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rU9mI9/1)

Comment: well, +1 for that site & effort, it might come in handy later, but, how do I test it? I'm zero at Perl